# Multiple many-to-many relations through the same model

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I need to connect multiple fields from one model to another using a ManyToManyField through the same relational table.

```
class First(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    foo = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Second',
        related_name='foo',
        through='RelationModel',
        through_fields=('first', 'second')
    )

    bar = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Second',
        related_name='bar',
        through='RelationModel',
        through_fields=('first', 'second')
    )

    baz = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Second',
        related_name='baz',
        through='RelationModel',
        through_fields=('first', 'second')
    )

class RelationModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    first = models.ForeignKey('First')
    second = models.ForeignKey('Second')

class Second(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

This results in the following error:

> myapp.First: (models.E003) The model has two many-to-many relations through the intermediate model 'myapp.RelationModel'.

How do I work around this? Why isn't this allowed?

Comment: Why would you need this? It is a system check error, not an exception, so you could just ignore the error message or silence it through [`SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#silenced-system-checks). However, I doubt that this is the best solution to the actual problem you're trying to solve here.